# Regex to match conditional IP address

Tags: regex, grep

I am wanting to grep for 192.168.22.xxx and 192.168.23.xxx. with a single grep statement where xxx can be any number.

I have tried

```
grep -Eo '192.168.2[2][3]\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

and

```
grep -Eo '173.235.2[2][3][\.][0-9]{1,3}'
```

But this does not return anything. What is the correct regex I need to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[2][3]` use `[23]`. Options should be included in the same `[]` group.

Also escape `.` every time:
`grep -Eo '192\.168\.2[23]\.[0-9]{1,3}'`

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/pL5pW4/1)

Comment: Ah! I was close lol.